# Как включить мини-Drawer (чтобы в закрытом состоянии было видно только иконки)?

Tags: android, material-design, toolbar, android-toolbar, android-drawer

К широко известному в узких кругах гугловскому примеру [Navigation Drawer](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) -

[image: screenshot]

я добавил Toolbar и еще один Drawer справа (вот [мой тестовый проект на GitHub](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/blob/q34/NavigationDrawerExample/)):

[image: app screenshot]

Вот мой новый [activity_main.xml](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/blob/q34/NavigationDrawerExample/res/layout/activity_main.xml):

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView 
            android:src="@drawable/ic_music_note_black_24dp"
            android:onClick="openActions"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/right_drawer"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

И новая [MainActivity.java](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/blob/q34/NavigationDrawerExample/src/com/example/android/navigationdrawerexample/MainActivity.java):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ListView mActionList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    private String[] mPlanetTitles;
    private String[] mActions;
    private int[] mIcons;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mPlanetTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
        mActions = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.music_actions);

        TypedArray ta = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.music_icons);
        mIcons = new int[ta.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < mIcons.length; i++)
            mIcons[i] = ta.getResourceId(i, R.drawable.ic_menu_black_24dp);
        ta.recycle();

        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
        mActionList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.right_drawer);

        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.drawer_list_item, mPlanetTitles) {
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                TextView view = (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                view.setCompoundDrawablePadding(24);
                view.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(
                    R.drawable.ic_stars_white_24dp, 0, 0, 0);
                return view;
            }
        });

        mActionList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mActions) {
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                TextView view = (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                view.setCompoundDrawablePadding(24);
                view.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(mIcons[position], 0, 0, 0);
                return view;
            }
        });

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,                  /* host Activity */
                mDrawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
                mToolbar,
                R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
                R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
                ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                mToolbar.setTitle(mTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                mToolbar.setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            selectItem(0);
        }
    }
```

Я хотел бы найти способ показывать в закрытом состоянии только иконки правого Drawer - то есть мини-режим описанный в [Material Design guide](http://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/navigation-drawer.html#navigation-drawer-behavior):

[image: мини режим]

Comment: Тупо рисовать эту мини-панель фиксированным layout/fragment под тулбаром не подойдет? Когда drawer открыт - он перекрывает этот layout и его не видно, drawer закрывается - он становится видимым. Или когда у вас эта мини-панель видима? Когда обе полнценные панели закрыты?

Comment: А с анимацией что тогда делать?

Comment: Есть какое то приложение, где это реализовано? Вообще, скорее всего это кастомный виджет. С гугловским `DrawerLayout` такое вряд ли возможно (если только для правого драйвера) потому, что смещение происходит сдвигом - иконки исчезают первыми, а здесь надо, чтобы была анимация раскрытия - драйвер не выдвигается, а как бы отрезается правая часть и постепенно отрезанное появляется

Comment: Вроде в Gmail для планшетов - сам проверить не могу

Comment: @AlexanderFarber, в gmail на планшете не совсем navigation drawer: [видео](https://youtu.be/mlG79RmZ3zw) (прошу прощения за качество, записал в samsung remote test lab). Вариант как там устроит? :)

Comment: Библиотека MaterialDrawer

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрел **GMail** на планшете - это точно не `NavigationDrawer` именно в части реализации - механика вообще не та.
Здесь при слайде контент сдвигается вместе с нав.драйвером, а не перекрывается им, как при работе `NavigationDrawer`, кроме того мини-вариант не является частью полного, а при слайде постепенно меняет прозрачность до невидимой.

Я думаю, что это вертикальный `Toolbar`, реализующий `CollapsingToolbarLayout` и `CoordinatorLayout` для самого псевдо-нав.бара - они оба входят в новую библиотеку гугла `support:design`.
Описаний [реализаций эффекта](http://antonioleiva.com/collapsing-toolbar-layout/), но для горизонтального тулбара, достаточно в сети, где постепенное изменение прозрачности `Toolbar` (мини-драйвер) и замещение его другим виджетом, раскрывающимся со сдвигом контента. Их поведение полностью копирует механику нав.драйвера в **GMail**.
Конечно, в раздвигающийся контейнер в случае **GMail** помещается не картинка, а `NavigationView`, еще один виджет из библиотеки `support:design`, а на `Toolbar` помещены иконки быстрого доступа и немного изменена механика слайда.

[[image: скриншот]

Comment: Вот интересный блог про GMail: http://blog.sqisland.com/2015/01/partial-slidingpanelayout.html

Comment: @AlexanderFarber Хорошо, что вы нашли готовую реализацию, как это может быть  сделано .  Если вам не трудно, оформите ответом. Думаю, мой вариант будет попроще :) Если вообще получится его реализовать.

Comment: Извините, но Ваш текст (за который я проголосовал +1) - это еще не ответ.

Comment: Я не претендую на полноценный ответ, это лишь мои догадки. Просто в комментарий все не входило. Вы с чистейшей совестью можете забрать свой голос :) .

Comment: Я понял .. :) . Я говорю - не мой ответ признать верным, а напишите **свой ответ** с решением, которое **вы** нашли и отметьте его верным.